# Opening an old postscript file

Tags: postscript

I've been asked to open some old PostScript files created in the 90s on a Sun. I've tried GhostView, ImageMagick, InkScape, Gimp, Okular... and they all turn out a blank page, as does sending the file to a printer.

I've written a PS driver for a printer in the... 80s, so I'm understandably very rusty in the language.

Is there a way to get error messages when opening the file ? More generally, how can I debug PS files, such as single stepping ?

Here's a condensed version of one of the files I'm trying to open ( I removed several thousands of repetitive lines).

```
%!
270 rotate
%%Page:

statusdict (waittimeout) 0 put
%General PS definitions.

/l {lineto} def /m {moveto} def /rl {rlineto} def /rm {rmoveto} def
/sg {setgray} def /r {rotate} def /sc {scale} def /tr {translate} def
/gs {gsave} def /gr {grestore} def /st {stroke} def
/s {show} def /cm {28.3465 mul} def     %1 cm = 28.3465 units
/pi {3.14159} def /slw {setlinewidth} def
/ssf {scalefont setfont} def /trf {/Times-Roman findfont} def
/syf {/Symbol findfont} def 2 setlinejoin
%scale plot.
0.9 cm 2.5 cm tr        %Origo
%0.992 1.008 sc         %Rescale X,Y slightly so that they are equal
%               %on Apple laserprinter.
0.0195 cm 0.0195 cm sc      %scale plot so that 1000 units = 19.5 cm.
                %i.e. 1 unit = 19.5/1000 cm = 0.195 mm
trf 1 cm            %/Times Roman size = 1 cm
ssf 1 cm            %/Symbol size = 1 cm
1.5 slw             %Set default linewidth to be 0.5 units
                %(i.e. slightly LT 0.1 mm.
                %0.5128205 units=10./19.5 units=0.01 cm=0.1 mm
0 sg                %Set default grayness to be 0, which is black.

%Define plotsymbols, box,triangle, etc.
/box {newpath 0 0 m -0.5 -0.5 rm 0 1 rl 1 0 rl 0 -1 rl closepath} def
/bf     %Filled box
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def %Store the CTM in the varible ctmx
gs x y tr a r xs ys sc box cmtx setmatrix g sg fill gr} def
/bo     %Open box
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def
gs x y tr a r xs ys sc box cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/plus
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc newpath
-0.5 0 m 0.5 0 l 0 -0.5 m 0 0.5 l cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/r1 {0.5 2 sqrt div} def
/cross
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc newpath r1 neg
r1 neg m r1 r1 l r1 neg r1 m r1 r1 neg l cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/star
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc newpath -0.5 0 m
0.5 0 l 0 -0.5 m 0 0.5 l r1 neg r1 neg m r1 r1 l r1 neg r1 m r1 r1 neg l
cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/ef     %Filled ellipse (or circle if xs=ys)
{/g exch def /endangle exch def /startangle exch def /yrad exch def
/xrad exch def /angle exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr angle r xrad yrad sc newpath
0 0 0.5 startangle endangle arc cmtx setmatrix g sg fill gr} def
/eo     %Open ellipse (or circle if xs=ys)
{/g exch def /endangle exch def /startangle exch def /yrad exch def
/xrad exch def /angle exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr angle r xrad yrad sc newpath
0 0 0.5 startangle endangle arc cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/xt {0.5} def /y1t {xt 3 sqrt div} def /y2t {2 xt mul 3 sqrt div} def
/triangle {newpath xt neg y1t neg m 0 y2t l xt y1t neg l closepath} def
/tf     %Filled triangle
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc triangle
cmtx setmatrix g sg fill gr} def
/to     %Open triangle
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc triangle
cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
/h1 {0.5 3 sqrt div} def /h2 {h1 2 mul} def /h3 {h1 3 sqrt mul} def
/hexagone {newpath h1 h3 m h2 0 l h1 h3 neg l h1 neg h3 neg l h2 neg 0 l
h1 neg h3 l closepath} def
/hf     %Filled hexagone
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc hexagone
cmtx setmatrix g sg fill gr} def
/ho     %Open hexagone
{/g exch def /ys exch def /xs exch def /a exch def /y exch def /x exch def
/cmtx matrix currentmatrix def gs x y tr a r xs ys sc hexagone
cmtx setmatrix g sg st gr} def
trf 10.00 ssf
1.00 slw
0.00 sg
476.1 382.4 m
472.9 382.5 l
471.6 382.5 l
468.4 382.5 l
465.3 382.6 l
419.5 280.2 90.0 6.1 6.1 0.0 360.0 0.00 ef
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 180.0 m
476.1 600.0 l
476.1 180.0 m
404.7 600.0 l
476.1 180.0 m
328.7 600.0 l
476.1 180.0 m
242.3 600.0 l
476.1 180.0 m
st 476.1 180.0 m
206.1 513.7 l
476.1 180.0 m
206.1 414.9 l
476.1 180.0 m
206.1 341.7 l
476.1 180.0 m
206.1 281.9 l
476.1 180.0 m
206.1 229.4 l
239.2 180.0 m
206.1 180.0 l
476.1 180.0 90.0 70.0 67.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 140.0 135.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 210.0 202.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 280.0 270.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 350.0 337.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 420.0 405.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 490.0 472.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 560.0 540.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 630.0 607.5 0.0 62.7 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 700.0 675.0 0.0 53.1 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 770.0 742.5 0.0 46.7 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 840.0 810.0 0.0 41.8 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 910.0 877.5 22.6 38.0 0.00 eo
476.1 180.0 90.0 980.0 945.0 31.0 34.8 0.00 eo
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 899.0 m
473.5 899.0 l
471.1 899.0 l
468.4 899.0 l
465.8 899.1 l
st 442.4 800.0 m
442.6 803.1 l
440.5 806.3 l
437.6 810.4 l
419.3 797.0 90.0 6.1 6.1 0.0 360.0 0.00 ef
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 696.0 m
476.1 1116.0 l
476.1 696.0 m
404.7 1116.0 l
476.1 696.0 m
328.7 1116.0 l
476.1 696.0 m
242.3 1116.0 l
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 1029.7 l
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 930.9 l
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 857.7 l
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 797.9 l
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 745.4 l
239.2 696.0 m
206.1 696.0 l
476.1 696.0 90.0 70.0 67.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 140.0 135.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 210.0 202.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 280.0 270.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 350.0 337.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 420.0 405.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 490.0 472.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 560.0 540.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 630.0 607.5 0.0 62.7 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 700.0 675.0 0.0 53.1 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 770.0 742.5 0.0 46.7 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 840.0 810.0 0.0 41.8 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 910.0 877.5 22.6 38.0 0.00 eo
476.1 696.0 90.0 980.0 945.0 31.0 34.8 0.00 eo
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 384.4 m
876.7 384.4 l
871.7 384.3 l
870.3 384.3 l
868.9 384.4 l
821.2 281.8 90.0 6.1 6.1 0.0 360.0 0.00 ef
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 180.0 m
878.0 600.0 l
878.0 180.0 m
806.6 600.0 l
878.0 180.0 m
730.6 600.0 l
878.0 180.0 m
644.2 600.0 l
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 513.7 l
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 414.9 l
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 341.7 l
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 281.9 l
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 229.4 l
641.1 180.0 m
608.0 180.0 l
878.0 180.0 90.0 70.0 67.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 140.0 135.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 210.0 202.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 280.0 270.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 350.0 337.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 420.0 405.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 490.0 472.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 560.0 540.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 630.0 607.5 0.0 62.7 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 700.0 675.0 0.0 53.1 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 770.0 742.5 0.0 46.7 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 840.0 810.0 0.0 41.8 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 910.0 877.5 22.6 38.0 0.00 eo
878.0 180.0 90.0 980.0 945.0 31.0 34.8 0.00 eo
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 902.7 m
877.3 902.7 l
870.8 902.4 l
870.3 902.4 l
869.8 902.4 l
821.5 798.8 90.0 6.1 6.1 0.0 360.0 0.00 ef
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 696.0 m
878.0 1116.0 l
878.0 696.0 m
806.6 1116.0 l
878.0 696.0 m
730.6 1116.0 l
878.0 696.0 m
644.2 1116.0 l
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 1029.7 l
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 930.9 l
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 857.7 l
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 797.9 l
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 745.4 l
641.1 696.0 m
608.0 696.0 l
878.0 696.0 90.0 70.0 67.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 140.0 135.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 210.0 202.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 280.0 270.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 350.0 337.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 420.0 405.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 490.0 472.5 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 560.0 540.0 0.0 90.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 630.0 607.5 0.0 62.7 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 700.0 675.0 0.0 53.1 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 770.0 742.5 0.0 46.7 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 840.0 810.0 0.0 41.8 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 910.0 877.5 22.6 38.0 0.00 eo
878.0 696.0 90.0 980.0 945.0 31.0 34.8 0.00 eo
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
1.35 slw
938.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 1.00 bo
938.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
911.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.95 bo
911.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
884.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.90 bo
884.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
857.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.85 bo
857.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
830.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.80 bo
830.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
803.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.75 bo
803.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
776.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.70 bo
776.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
749.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.65 bo
749.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
722.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.60 bo
722.8 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
695.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.55 bo
695.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
668.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.50 bo
668.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
641.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.45 bo
641.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
614.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.40 bo
614.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
587.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.35 bo
587.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
560.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.30 bo
560.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
533.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.25 bo
533.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
506.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.20 bo
506.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
479.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.15 bo
479.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
452.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.10 bo
452.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
425.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.05 bo
425.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
398.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
398.7 1233.7 90.0 22.5 22.5 0.00 bo
trf 20.92 ssf
gs 950.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( < 0.15) s
gr
gs 923.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 0.15 - 0.33) s
gr
gs 896.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 0.33 - 0.50) s
gr
gs 869.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 0.50 - 0.68) s
gr
gs 842.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 0.68 - 0.86) s
gr
gs 815.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 0.86 - 1.03) s
gr
gs 788.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.03 - 1.21) s
gr
gs 761.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.21 - 1.38) s
gr
gs 734.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.38 - 1.56) s
gr
gs 707.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.56 - 1.74) s
gr
gs 680.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.74 - 1.91) s
gr
gs 653.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 1.91 - 2.09) s
gr
gs 626.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.09 - 2.27) s
gr
gs 599.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.27 - 2.44) s
gr
gs 572.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.44 - 2.62) s
gr
gs 545.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.62 - 2.79) s
gr
gs 518.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.79 - 2.97) s
gr
gs 491.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 2.97 - 3.15) s
gr
gs 464.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 3.15 - 3.32) s
gr
gs 437.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( 3.32 - 3.50) s
gr
gs 410.0 1256.2 m 90.0 r
( > 3.50) s
gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
2.00 slw
950.0 0.0 m
50.0 0.0 l
50.0 1200.0 l
950.0 1200.0 l
950.0 0.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 180.0 m
476.1 600.0 l
480.2 180.0 m
476.1 180.0 l
480.2 187.0 m
476.1 187.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 14.1 ssf
gs 501.4 167.0 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 501.4 237.0 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 501.4 307.0 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 501.4 377.0 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 501.4 447.0 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
gs 501.4 517.0 m 90.0 r (0.50) s gr
gs 501.4 587.0 m 90.0 r (0.60) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 180.0 m
206.1 180.0 l
476.1 175.9 m
476.1 180.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
gs 480.7 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 413.2 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 345.7 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 278.2 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 210.7 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
206.1 180.0 m
206.1 600.0 l
206.1 180.0 m
202.1 180.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 12.55 ssf
gs 133.2 180.0 m 90.0 r
( Z=58 N= 88 A=146 n:vacuum p:vacuum G\(P+P) s
trf 8.37 ssf
0 4.18 rm
(+\)) s
trf 12.55 ssf
0 4.18 neg rm
(^2) s
gr
gs 149.4 180.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (w) s trf 12.55 ssf
(=0.000 I= 0.0 E= -2.23 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(2=0.166 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (g) s trf 12.55 ssf
(= 0.4 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(4= 0.043.) s
gr
gs 165.6 180.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(p=1.186 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(n=0.732 Routhian.) s
gr
gs 181.8 180.0 m 90.0 r
(Min = -2.22 MeV, max = 9.62 MeV.) s
gr
950.0 0.0 m
st 950.0 0.0 m
50.0 0.0 l
50.0 1200.0 l
950.0 1200.0 l
950.0 0.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 696.0 m
476.1 1116.0 l
480.2 696.0 m
476.1 696.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 14.1 ssf
gs 501.4 683.0 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 501.4 753.0 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 501.4 823.0 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 501.4 893.0 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 501.4 963.0 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
gs 501.4 1033.0 m 90.0 r (0.50) s gr
gs 501.4 1103.0 m 90.0 r (0.60) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
476.1 696.0 m
206.1 696.0 l
476.1 692.0 m
476.1 696.0 l
469.4 692.0 m
469.4 696.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 12.55 ssf
gs 133.2 696.0 m 90.0 r
( Z=58 N= 88 A=146 n:vacuum p:vacuum G\(P+P) s
trf 8.37 ssf
0 4.18 rm
(+\)) s
trf 12.55 ssf
0 4.18 neg rm
(^2) s
gr
gs 149.4 696.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (w) s trf 12.55 ssf
(=0.049 I= 0.8 E= -2.25 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(2=0.167 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (g) s trf 12.55 ssf
(= 0.3 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(4= 0.043.) s
gr
gs 165.6 696.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(p=1.185 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(n=0.731 Routhian.) s
gr
gs 181.8 696.0 m 90.0 r
(Min = -2.24 MeV, max = 9.56 MeV.) s
gr
950.0 0.0 m
50.0 0.0 l
50.0 1200.0 l
950.0 1200.0 l
950.0 0.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 180.0 m
878.0 600.0 l
882.0 180.0 m
878.0 180.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 14.1 ssf
gs 903.3 167.0 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 903.3 237.0 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 903.3 307.0 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 903.3 377.0 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 903.3 447.0 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
gs 903.3 517.0 m 90.0 r (0.50) s gr
gs 903.3 587.0 m 90.0 r (0.60) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 180.0 m
608.0 180.0 l
878.0 175.9 m
878.0 180.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
gs 882.6 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 815.1 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 747.6 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 680.1 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 612.6 137.8 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
608.0 180.0 m
608.0 600.0 l
608.0 180.0 m
603.9 180.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 12.55 ssf
gs 535.1 180.0 m 90.0 r
( Z=58 N= 88 A=146 n:vacuum p:vacuum G\(P+P) s
trf 8.37 ssf
0 4.18 rm
(+\)) s
trf 12.55 ssf
0 4.18 neg rm
(^2) s
gr
gs 551.3 180.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (w) s trf 12.55 ssf
(=0.098 I= 1.7 E= -2.31 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(2=0.168 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (g) s trf 12.55 ssf
(= 0.1 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(4= 0.043.) s
gr
gs 567.5 180.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(p=1.174 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(n=0.723 Routhian.) s
gr
gs 583.7 180.0 m 90.0 r
(Min = -2.29 MeV, max = 9.37 MeV.) s
gr
950.0 0.0 m
50.0 0.0 l
50.0 1200.0 l
950.0 1200.0 l
950.0 0.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 696.0 m
878.0 1116.0 l
882.0 696.0 m
878.0 696.0 l
882.0 703.0 m
st 886.1 1116.0 m
878.0 1116.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 14.1 ssf
gs 903.3 683.0 m 90.0 r (0.00) s gr
gs 903.3 753.0 m 90.0 r (0.10) s gr
gs 903.3 823.0 m 90.0 r (0.20) s gr
gs 903.3 893.0 m 90.0 r (0.30) s gr
gs 903.3 963.0 m 90.0 r (0.40) s gr
gs 903.3 1033.0 m 90.0 r (0.50) s gr
gs 903.3 1103.0 m 90.0 r (0.60) s gr
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
878.0 696.0 m
608.0 696.0 l
878.0 692.0 m
878.0 696.0 l
0 0 m st 0 0 m
0 0 m st 0 0 m
trf 12.55 ssf
gs 535.1 696.0 m 90.0 r
( Z=58 N= 88 A=146 n:vacuum p:vacuum G\(P+P) s
trf 8.37 ssf
0 4.18 rm
(+\)) s
trf 12.55 ssf
0 4.18 neg rm
(^2) s
gr
gs 551.3 696.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (w) s trf 12.55 ssf
(=0.147 I= 2.7 E= -2.42 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(2=0.169 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (g) s trf 12.55 ssf
(= -0.3 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (b) s trf 12.55 ssf
(4= 0.043.) s
gr
gs 567.5 696.0 m 90.0 r
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(p=1.155 ) s
syf 12.55 ssf (D) s trf 12.55 ssf
(n=0.709 Routhian.) s
gr
gs 583.7 696.0 m 90.0 r
(Min = -2.40 MeV, max = 9.05 MeV.) s
gr
trf 41.85 ssf
gs 936.5 480.0 m 90.0 r
(X=) s
syf 41.85 ssf (b) s trf 41.85 ssf
trf 27.90 ssf
0 6.97 neg rm
(2) s
trf 41.85 ssf
0 6.97 rm
(cos\() s
syf 41.85 ssf (g) s trf 41.85 ssf
(+30\)) s
gr
gs 590.0 60.0 m 180.0 r
(Y=) s
syf 41.85 ssf (b) s trf 41.85 ssf
trf 27.90 ssf
0 6.97 neg rm
(2) s
trf 41.85 ssf
0 6.97 rm
(sin\() s
syf 41.85 ssf (g) s trf 41.85 ssf
(+30\)) s
gr
trf 15.11 ssf
gs 946.5 6.9 m 90.0 r
(Tue May 26 17:05:29 1998 17:05:29 NSG Liverpool) s
gr
st
showpage
```

Running the file in gs:

```
$ gs
GS>ce146_1.ps run
Error: /undefined in ce146_1.ps
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
--dict:1200/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Resource temporarily unavailable
Current file position is 11
```

Comment: I think you've succeeded in *opening* the file (after all, PostScript programs are written in ordinary text).  What you are trying to do is to *run* the program in an interpreter.  AFAIK, there should be no compatibility problems with newer interpreters, but in any case, this isn't a programming issue.

Comment: I've added the output from gs when I run the file.

Comment: `(ce146_1.ps) run` the filename should be a string and strings are put into () or straight in cmdline `gs ce146_1.ps `

Comment: If you make the file available I'll take a look. As you see from your usage of GS above, Ghostscript will already give you any errors that occur, so if its not saying anything, then either there are no errors, or the file is executing inside stopped. I'd guess that the '270 rotate' might be a problem, especially of the media isn't correct (as it might rotate the content off the media), you could try removing that. The file doesn't appear to send media request (setpage in old level 1 code, or sometimes just 'A4' or similar).

Comment: FWIW if I take your (truncated you say) file above, and run it, then the output is blank. If I remove the "270 rotate" then I get output. I'd have to say its the rotation (without a corresponding translate) throwing the content off the media

Comment: If I comment out the 270 rotate, I see the file. I will try on the other ones and run it by the user to see if that's the whole of it, but so far so good, thanks.

Comment: @KenS: I think your comment above qualifies as a proper answer to this.

Comment: Yes it does, as all the other files had either wrong rotate or translate. Are there ways to mark a comment as a solution ?

Comment: No, I'd have to make it into an answer, but that's fine, I'm just happy that you have an explanation now.

Comment: @KenS if you wouldn't mind making your comment into an answer, that has the advantage that a) SO no longer marks the question as "unanswered", and b) dargaud can then accept the answer, and SO no longer marks the question as having no accepted answer.

Comment: Well, if you insist....

Comment: <shameless plug> There is a [ps debugger that can single-step](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/debug.ps) </shameless plug>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PostScript file in question (and by the comment from the original poster, similar files) starts with a '270 rotate'.

This moves the marking content of the program by rotation around the 0,0 co-ordinate, which is **not** the centre of the page, its the lower left corner. The result of this is that the marking operations then take place 'off the page' resulting in a blank page. The program should include a 'translate' to move the origin either before or after rotation, so that the marking operations are moved back onto the area of the media.

Level 1 PostScript often relied upon 'just knowing' the characteristics of a device, so such tricks were not uncommon back then.